# efficient SQL query to get rows with different conditions in different times

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, query-optimization

Suppose we have a table `users`:

`user_id, timestamp, condition_a, condition_b`

Each user session is a row with same user id, different timestamp and arbitrary conditions a and/or b.

I want to do queries like:

- Users who had condition a from t1 to t2 and NOT condition b from t3 to t4.
- Users who had condition a before t1 and condition b after t3.

One way to do it is with subqueries:

for the 1st example above:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
user_id IN 
(SELECT user_id WHERE timestamp BETWEEN t1 AND t2 AND condition_a =1 )
AND user_id NOT IN
(SELECT user_id WHERE timestamp BETWEEN t2 AND t3 AND condition_b =1 )
```

This looks very inefficient to me since it will have to scan the table several times.

Is there a more efficient way to do this that only needs to scan the table once?
(this is for presto eventually, partitions are by time blocks)

Comment: Your subqueries are not syntactically correct.  They need a `from` clause.

Answer (score 1):

I would calls the table `sessions`, not users.  So, let's start from there.  If you have a table `users`, then `user_id` should be the primary key (or natural key in a type-2 dimension).

One method to get the`user_ids` is aggregation:

```
SELECT s.user_id
FROM sessions s
WHERE (timestamp BETWEEN t1 AND t2 AND condition_a = 1) OR
      (timestamp BETWEEN t2 AND t3 AND condition_b = 1)
GROUP BY s.user_id
HAVING SUM(timestamp BETWEEN t1 AND t2 AND condition_a = 1) > 0 AND
       SUM(timestamp BETWEEN t2 AND t3 AND condition_b = 1) > 0;
```

You can join back to the original data (or use `IN` or `EXISTS`) to get the detailed rows, if you like.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! on both comments.

Answer (score 0):

In the original attempt, change `IN` to `EXISTS`.

Add these:

```
INDEX(condition_a, timestamp, user_id)
INDEX(condition_b, timestamp, user_id)
```

The statement of the problem is imprecise.  What do you mean by "had condition a from t1 to t2"?

- One row exists with 'a' in that time range, or
- Multiple rows, one of which has 'a', or
- Multiple rows, all of which have 'a'??

`IN` is more costly than `EXISTS` because it must find all of the rows.  `EXISTS` only handles the first two meanings.

For the second question I suggest

```
SELECT u.*
    FROM users AS u
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM ... WHERE condition_a AND timestamp < t1
                                       AND user_id = u.user_id )
      AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM ... WHERE condition_b AND timestamp > t3
                                       AND user_id = u.user_id )
```

together with

```
INDEX(user_id, condition_a, timestamp)
INDEX(user_id, condition_b, timestamp)
```

This would probably be better (for getting the user_ids) and would need only my first pair of indexes:

```
   ( SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM ... WHERE condition_a AND timestamp < t1 )
   UNION ALL    -- 'ALL' is deliberate, for GROUP and HAVING
   ( SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM ... WHERE condition_b AND timestamp > t3 )
   GROUP BY user_id
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

To get user info:

```
SELECT u.*
    FROM ( that union ) AS v
    JOIN users AS u  USING(user_id)
```